# Unable to create initial connections of pool Async Jersey+Spring+Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, jdbc

I have a web service asynchronously with Jersey + Spring and use Tomcat 7.

I have set server.xml in tomcat like:

```
<Connector port="8080" address="localhost"     
 maxThreads="250" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
 emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
 enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
 connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

I have in my beam.xml this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="/config/application.properties" />      

    <!-- Initialization for data source JDBC -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${jdbc.initialSize}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="${jdbc.maxActive}"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${jdbc.maxIdle}" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="${jdbc.minIdle}" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="${jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
    <bean id="studentJDBCTemplate" class="com.me.database.StudentJDBCTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Initialization for TransactionManager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    ...
```

And in my StudentJDBCTemplate i have:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;  
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;

public class StudentJDBCTemplate implements StudenteDAO {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    private int p_id;
    private int c_id;


    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void setTransactionManager(
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }
```

i try with Jmeter with 3 http sampler request and a Thread Group with 4 numbers of threads, ramp-up period 1 and loop count 1. But when i try to execute this test i have this error:

```
PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
GRAVE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve with this; I put in context.xml on my Tomcat config this:

```
<Resource 
auth="Container" 
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" 
maxWait="10000" 
name="jdbc/UsersDB" 
password="" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" 
username="root"/>
```

change my beam.xml config with:

```
<!-- Initialization for data source JDBC -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/UsersDB"/>
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Add in Tomcat directory/lib `mysql-connector-java-VERSION-bin.jar` and in my project

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-dbcp2-2.0.1.jar 
commons-pool2-2.2.jar
```